# link css file in another folder doesnt work

Tags: php, html, css

im using appserver and i want to link style.css

```
.header {
    height: "40px";
    background-color: "red"
}
```

in my index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ar">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css"/>
        <title>بام للسيارات | تبضع اينما كنت</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it didnt work i dont know why can someone help me

[image]

Comment: are you sure CSS/ diractory is correct?

Comment: Where is the CSS folder relative to the html file? Your current assumption is that your style.css file is inside a folder called CSS. Your HTML file is assumed to be in the same directory as the CSS folder

Comment: Add the directory structure of the website.

Comment: @A.S.Roma yes it's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your CSS is incorrect,

```
.header {
    height: "40px";
    background-color: "red"
}
```

Noticing the **quotes** in your values, which are invalid in CSS syntax. It should be,

```
.header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

After reviewing your code, there is no other coding errors. But your have serious errors with your file encodings.

index.php was encoded in UTF-16LE, and your didn't declare your charset in the `<head>` section nor the BOM (neither does your css file, which is encoded in UTF-8). So the browser guesses the resource files are also encoded in UTF-16LE, which read two bytes as one character. So your CSS became totally meaningless to the CSS parser, as it reads `栮慥敤⁲ൻ †栠楥桧㩴㐠瀰㭸਍††慢正牧畯摮挭汯牯›敲㭤਍ൽ`.

So the fix is pretty straight forward,

1. Add `charset` declaration at the begining of your `<head>`
2. Save your index.php as `UTF-8` encoding *or* add `charset="utf-8"` to `<link>`.

Comment: Can you pack your code and upload it to dropbox or something, then post the link, so we can have a look?

Comment: @xiaoyi: Super... Hats off to that observation!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ar">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css"/>
        <title>بام للسيارات | تبضع اينما كنت</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have packed your code ger it from [here](http://copy.com/LnCYyw03CsjYry2o/Carage.zip?download=1)